# Is there any other way to get Laravel to reload env variables?

Tags: laravel, caching, environment-variables, config, reset

I have a shared hosting account on a well known host.

I have my Laravel site uploaded and functioning for the most part. But I had to make an env change. Now I can't get Laravel to see the change.

I know this is common issue. I have tried running the artisan commands to clear config and cache (php artisan config:cache  & php artisan cache:clear  ) but this fails with an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home4/cmatthewc/cvbaptistapp/artisan on line 33

Is there any other way to get Laravel to refresh its cache from env?

TY in advance...

Comment: what version of laravel? Also, thats a PHP error in the artisan file, did you modify it?

Comment: (Laravel 5.6 ) I did not modify the artisan file. But I have separated the core files from public ones and that might have broken something I am not aware of.

Comment: wait, does your laravel project have a .env ?

Comment: yes. I changed the env file for mail and I can't get Laravel to see the new variable values.

Comment: Was it working prior to this? also, would you mind sharing the new env variables? substitute the values but make them structurally the same.

Comment: The site works. the artisan commands don't.  (this configuration works on my dev machine )                                                                                                      MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io 
MAIL_PORT=2525 
MAIL_USERNAME=username
 MAIL_PASSWORD=password 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: The error tells me that there is a PHP error in your artisan file, maybe verify it looks the same as `https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan#L33`, also, did you install all the composer dependencies? that could be causing it as well

Comment: Also, do you know the PHP version of the box?

Comment: PHP 5.4.45 (cli) I set my environment to use PHP 7. Thank you for the artisan reference, yes mine is the same to the GitHub file

Comment: Ahh, that is your issue. I'll post my answer below, as it contains documentation quotes and links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### THE ISSUE

The issue lies in the `php cli` version of the server. Laravel 5.6 expects you to have `PHP 7.1.3` or greater.

More specifically, the exact reason you're getting this error, from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class):

> Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name
>   resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name
>   of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly
>   useful with namespaced classes.

And if you look on line 33 in the [`artisan` file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan#L33) in your project root:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

And since the server is running 5.4 when you run commands via the CLI, PHP has no idea what the syntax means, so it throws an error.

### THE FIX

In order to fix this, you'll need to upgrade your PHP version.