# How can I change the Laravel Artisan CLI PHP version?

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, version, laravel-artisan

I posted a question about clearing the cache [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107273/is-there-any-other-way-to-get-laravel-to-reload-env-variables)
the problem was I can't clear cache after editing the .env file. That is still my real problem. (I can't reset the server and I cant use artisan cmds)

But this problem needs to be solved before I can solve that one:

I cannot run artisan commands. I have a shared hosting account where my environment PHP version is 7.14 the PHP artisan CLI is using the default PHP 5.4 so I cannot do: php artisan cache:clear etc

I have tried things like

```
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
```

And...

```
    $process = new Process('/opt/php71/lib artisan config:cache');
    $process->run();
```

Keep in mind that my application works fine, and PHP version is 7.14 according to PHPINFO.

So how can I either get Laravel to clear its cache another way or get artisan to run using a specific PHP version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where my environment PHP version is 7.14 the PHP artisan CLI is using the default PHP 5.4

No, artisan will use whatever version your environment is set to run – [the shebang](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan#L1) looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

And if you're calling it like `php artisan ...` then the shebang isn't even used. In either case, you should [adjust your path](https://superuser.com/questions/488173/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux) so that PHP 7.1 is called when you run `php` (i.e. the directory containing PHP 7.1 should come before the one containing 5.4) and it will work fine.

Comment: I have wamp installed on my windows laptop. I was trying to change the php version from the wamp manager but wamp manager doesn't affect artisan command. Thanks +1